# Difference between two methods of creating a Web Service in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

Somebody asked a question about how to create a web service (as opposed to a WCF service) using VS2010, and I answered it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494818/how-can-i-add-a-web-service-project-using-visual-studio-2010).

My extended answer to the question wonders about the difference between a web service created using the .NET 3.5 Web Service template, and one created in a .NET 4 Web Application template.  The former has assembly bindings pointing to ASP.NET 3.5, but the latter appears to default to ASP.NET 4, and which presumably contains a newer version of implementing web services (or maybe it simply back references v3.5?).

So, is there anyone with a good idea of the difference between the two, or perhaps knowledge that there is no difference?

Comment: Are you talking about the 2 different ways to start an ASP project (WebSite vs WebApp) ?

Comment: No, the question doesn't address this aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question by way of saying: I don't think it matters.